# How do I setup windows 2012 R2 to act as a Secondary DNS server?

Tags: dns, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows server 2012 R2 box running as my domain controller and I am having some trouble with DNS. I have DNS records setup on the DC for a few sites that we want to have the internal IP different than the external IP. Our main DNS records are on godaddy.com. So for example the DNS record on the DC would be set to 192.168.1.2 mx.foo.com and the one on godaddy would be 173.12.58.1 mx.foo.com. This works fine but the problem I am having is if I make a new DNS record on godaddy the Domain Controller won't resolve the address until it is manually added.

Right now if I add a DNS record in godaddy anyone that is using the Domain Controller as their DNS server will not be able to resolve the url until I add it to the Domain Controller. So if I add new.foo.com pointing to 173.25.24.2 on godaddy the users on the Domain Controller won't be able to resolve new.foo.com unitl I add it to the Domain Controller. Is there a way to have Server 2012 lookup this address automatically?

I have added godaddy's nameservers as the SOA and as the NS in the DC but it still doesn't resolve records from the godaddy. I am sure this is an easy answer but I can't find anything on google for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set godaddy's DNS server as a forwarder. Open `dnsmgmt.msc` and rigck-click your *Server Name*, Choose `Properties`, under `Forwarders` tab choose `Edit` and add godaddy's DNS IP address. From now on, every record not found on the local DNS records, will be recursively queried from godaddy and also cached in local DNS server.
[image]

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad idea.  Forwarders are used for the DNS server to resolve all requests. By setting GoDaddy as your forwarder, you are pumping ALL your DNS lookups through them.  They are not obliged to answer to queries for zones they are not authoritative for.  The question was how to act as a secondary, and that requires zone transfers.

Comment: If you read the question, you can easily say that he has no idea what "Secondary Zone" is. The title says: *"How do I setup windows 2012 R2 to act as a Secondary DNS server?"* (see? *Secondary DNS Server*, not *Secondary DNS zone*!) and then *I have added godaddy's nameservers as the SOA and as the NS in the DC but it still doesn't resolve records from the godaddy. I am sure this is an easy answer but I can't find anything on google for it.* Sure he has no idea what a secondary zone is! He just want's to resolve address before their private address is added in local DNS.The title is confusing!

Comment: *"By setting GoDaddy as your forwarder, you are pumping ALL your DNS lookups through them."* No! just the queries that are not available in local DNS itself. And you can also limit it to your domain name using conditional forwarders.

Comment: OK I can see how you came to that conclusion, but I'd be wary of making that call without clarifying with the asker.  Conditional forwarding will reduce issues around looking up other zones, but the secondary would still be subject to TTL of records, and could therefore expire cached entries and make the zone unavailable to local if godaddy DNS servers were not accessible.  Also, the asker talks about adding records to their local DNS, for which they must have set up a zone

Comment: You are right, no argument on the benefits of secondary zones over forwarders. I clarified my answer to the asker, so if he believes it's not the proper solution, He's all set to downvote it. He clarified that he wants to resolve new addresses as he creates new records in Godaddy, if he came up asking "Please guide me through creating a secondary zone of my primary DNS zone on Godaddy" then for sure, my answer is totally unrelated.

Comment: I tried to add godaddy as a forwarder and it didn't seem to work. I did however from your answer come across what I think is the solution. On improve.dk he says to use a zone for every subdomain and don't make one for the main domain [Here](http://improve.dk/partial-dns-forwarding-using-individual-windows-dns-zones/)

Comment: He says *"As this record should only be made available internally, we can’t just add it to the public DNS records for the domain."* which is not your case I guess? You need to create a secondary zone (as suggested by @Adrien) that replicates with your DNS zone on Godaddy. However, they have to allow your DC to perform zone transfers.

Comment: Which address did you add as the forwarder? Can you resolve one of your addresses on your DC by running `nslookup new.foo.com x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is the DNS address of godaddy? If not, then you're using the wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

Acting as a secondary DNS server requires the ability to do zone transfers from the primary server.

If the primary DNS server is off-site, then you may not be getting notifications from the primary about addition of new records.  I don't know of a way to schedule these, but you can manually trigger a transfer from the master by right-clicking on the domain in DNS manager, and choosing "Transfer from Master"

Godaddy has an option for notifying secondary DNS servers, they call it Premium DNS.  Your DNS server would need to be able to receive the NOTIFY (zone change notification) from the godaddy primary.

You may be better off making godaddy the secondary.  Then you would just edit records in your local primary which would be pushed across to godaddy.

see https://nz.godaddy.com/help/what-is-secondary-dns-797

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts from your link in case it gets removed in the future?